# How can I run a runtime generated query with Pageable in Spring Data?

Tags: java, spring, java-8, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a runtime generated JPQL as a String, and a PageAble object. I want to run the JPQL query with Pageable. How can I do that?

E.g.: I want a solution like this with runtime generated Query string.

```
@Query("select u from User u")
Page<User> findUsers(Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: so you need to create repository interface to make 

    @Repository
    public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User,Long>{
       @Query("select u from User u")
       Page<User> findUsers(Pageable pageable);
    }   check this link https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-part-seven-pagination/

Comment: I believe that is not possible. The spring-data built-in mechanism are all bound to the model type (a.k.a. User).

Answer (score 0):

> Attempt 1

To use a query generated at runtime, the repository method will have to be declared as

```
@Query("?1") Page<User>
findUsers(String query, Pageable pageable)
```

However, `@Query` is parsed at the time of initializing the application context, so this approach will fail because `?1` on its own is not a valid JPQL expression.

> Attempt 2

If you use

```
@Query("?1", nativeQuery = true)
```

the context will initialize and you will be able to pass the generated query to the method, but the `Pageable` parameter will be ignored because the query passed as the method parameter is used as-is.

So, in short, no, what you are looking for cannot be done with a `Pageable`.

---

> Attempt 3

If you must generate the query at runtime, you must perform the pagination yourself as well. An example query with MySQL as the underlying database:

```
@Query("select u from user u order by last_name, first_name offset (?1 - 1) * ?2 limit ?2", nativeQuery = true)
Page<User> findUsers(int page, int pageSize);
```

Do note that `offset` and `limit` are specific to MySQL and Postgres. There may be a different syntax for other database products.